# What is a simple way to run Gazebo with no graphics?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to run Gazebo without the X11 window it creates.

If I am simulating vision, I still need to run OGRE to generate images.

Thanks,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/541/what-is-a-simple-way-to-run-gazebo-with-no-graphics?/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2012-12-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We plan on adding a tutorial for this, but in the meantime, here's a quick explanation. When you launch gazebo, there are two programs that are run: gzserver and gzclient. The program gzserver does all the simulation, even rendering for camera simulation. The interactive window is opened by gzclient.

To open a specific world, type `gzserver specific.world`.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2012-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2012-12-21**:
I'm still a couple of versions back, but you'd also need to make sure that you've set the DISPLAY environment appropriately if you're not directly using the console..